# Portfolio selection according to median

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, columnsorting

I have to write my masterthesis and want to create two portfolios from a dataframe with 218 rows (stocks) and 157 columns (monthly marketcapitalization and one column date) using the median as the boundary. That's what I got so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\chris\Dropbox\Masterarbeit\Data\SMB\MarketCap.xlsx')
df.set_index('Company Name')
df.info()
```

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 218 entries, 0 to 217
Columns: 158 entries, Identifier (RIC) to CM-154
dtypes: datetime64ns, float64(155), object(2)
memory usage: 269.2+ KB

```
dfm = df.median()
dfm.to_frame
```

Which is this big: Length: 155, dtype: float64>

```
df_large = df.loc['CM0':'CM-154'] >= dfm
```

This gives me then the error code: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and ndarray

The data looks like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZXdB.jpg)

I hope this is enough information and someone could help me. Thank you very much in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: I'm slightly unclear about what you're trying to achieve. I believe you currently have a df with company names as the row index, datetimes as the column index and the values being the share price. You want two dfs, one which contains the values above the median (for the company across the time span) and one which contains the values below the median (for the company across the time span)?

Comment: How about `df_large = df.loc[:,'CM0':'CM-154'] >= dfm`

Comment: @OD1995 exactly.

Comment: @BaronLegendre this gives the same error message: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and ndarray.

Comment: Could you show some data that includes like first 10 columns and 20 rows

Comment: @BaronLegendre edited the post, hope this is enough.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vJcQeDf4Y2dIbAugQrBi-LglosMUCUbU/view?usp=sharing) I use,

```
df
###
```

[image]

```
df.dtypes
###
regularMarketTime    datetime64[ns]
marketCap                     int64
marketCap0                  float64
marketCap1                  float64
marketCap2                  float64
marketCap3                  float64
marketCap4                  float64
```

```
dfm = df.median(numeric_only=True)
dfm
###
marketCap     8.053821e+11
marketCap0    8.366658e+11
marketCap1    8.521972e+11
marketCap2    8.215257e+11
marketCap3    8.034372e+11
marketCap4    8.254509e+11
dtype: float64
```

```
df2 = df.loc[:,'marketCap':'marketCap4'] >= dfm
df2
```

```
      marketCap  marketCap0  marketCap1  marketCap2  marketCap3  marketCap4
AAPL       True        True        True        True        True        True
GOOG       True        True        True        True        True        True
RY        False       False       False       False       False       False
HPQ       False       False       False       False       False       False
```

Furthermore, I think you gotta check your `'CM0':'CM-154'` like `df.loc[:,'CM0':'CM-154'].dtypes`

For clustering,

```
above_median = df.loc[df2[df2['marketCap4'] == True].index]
below_median = df.loc[df2[~df2['marketCap4'] == True].index]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Awesome, it works now! Thank you! Do you by any chance know how I get out of this two portfolios, one with the stocks above the median and one with the stocks below?

Comment: Yeah, but taking my example, what if Apple’s market cap  at last become lower than the median, like lower than HPQ? Then how you decide which one to pick?

Comment: doesn't matter which one is lower. I just need two portfolios from which I can then calculate the monthly excess return. Thank you again for your time and effort!

Comment: I've updated my post, you may change my example's `marketCap4` as your `CM0` or something like that.

Comment: Now I would like that the portfolio is changed for every month, do you know by any chance a easy way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea whether your data varied with time, I thought `MC0`, `MC1` already are marketCap per year.

Comment: I'm not sure if I didn't have a mistake in my data. I know it's quite much to ask for, but may I send you my file to check?